# Horst (pD*) compared to OWL2-RL

Tags: owl, semantic-web, graphdb

We are using [GraphDB 8.4.0](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/8.4/free/release-notes.html) as a triple store for a large data integration project. We want to make use of the reasoning capabilities, and are trying to decide between using HORST (pD*) and OWL2-RL.
However, the literature describing these is quite dense. I *think* I understand that OWL2-RL is more "powerful", but I am unsure how so. Can anyone provide some examples of the differences between the two reasoners? What kinds of statements are inferred by OWL2-RL, but not HORST (and vice versa)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking this for bit, I came up with a concrete example. The Oral Health and Disease Ontology (http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/ohd.owl) contains three interrelated entities:

- a restored tooth
- a restored tooth surface that is part of the restored tooth
- a tooth restoration procedure that creates the restored tooth surface (e.g., when you have a filling placed in your tooth)

The axioms that define these entities are (using pseudo Manchester syntax):

```
restored tooth equivalent to Tooth and has part some dental restoration material
restored tooth surface subclass of part of restored tooth
filling procedure has specified output some restored tooth surface
```

The `has specified output` relation is a subproperty of the `has participant` relation, and the `has participant` relation contains the property chain:

```
has_specified_input o 'is part of'
```

The reason for this property chain is for reasoner to infer that if a tooth surface participates in a procedure, then the whole tooth that the surface is part of participates in the procedure, and, furthermore, the patient that the tooth is part of also participates in the procedure (due to the transitivity of part of).

As a concrete example, let define some individuals (using pseudo rdf):

```
:patient#1 a :patient .
:tooth#1 a :tooth; :part-of :patient#1
:restored-occlusal#1 a :restored-occlusal-surface; :part-of tooth#1 .
:procedure#1 :has-specified-output :restored-occlusal#1 .
```

Suppose you want to query for all restored teeth:

```
select ?tooth where {?tooth a :restored-tooth}
```

RDFS-Plus reasoning will not find any restored teeth b/c it doesn't reason over equivalent classes. But, OWL-Horst and OWL2-RL will find such teeth.

Now, suppose you want to find all patients that underwent (i.e. participated in) a tooth restoration procedure:

```
select ?patient where {
    ?patient a patient: .
    ?proc a tooth_restoration_procedure:; has_participant: ?patient .
}
```

Again, RDFS-Plus will not find any patients, and neither will OWL-Horst b/c this inference requires reasoning over the `has participant` property chain. OWL2-RL is needed in order to make this inference.

I hope this example is helpful for the interested reader :).

I welcome comments to improve the example. Please keep any comments within the scope of trying to make the example clearer. Its purpose is to give insight into what these different levels of reasoning do and not to give advice about which reasoner is most appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

Brill, inside there GraphDB there is a single rule engine, which supports different reasoning profiles, depending on the rule-set which was selected. The predefined rule-sets are part of the distribution - look at the PIE files in folder configs/rules. One can also take one of the existing profiles and tailor it to her needs (e.g. remove a rule, which is not necessary).

The fundamental difference between OWL2 RL and what we call OWL-Horst (pD*) is that OWL2RL pushes the limits of which OWL constructs can be supported using this type of entailment rules. OWL Horst is limited to RDFS (subClassOf, subSpropertyOf, domain and range) plus what was popular in the past as OWL Lite: sameAs, equivalentClass, equivalentProperty, SymmetricProperty, TransitiveProperty, inverseOf, FunctionalProperty, InverseFunctionalProperty. There is also partial support for: intersectionOf, someValuesFrom, hasValue, allValuesFrom.

What OWL 2 RL adds on top is support for AsymmetricProperty, IrreflexiveProperty, propertyChainAxiom, AllDisjointProperties, hasKey, unionOf, complementOf, oneOf, differentFrom, AllDisjointClasses and all the property cardinality primitives. It also adds more complete support for intersectionOf, someValuesFrom, hasValue, allValuesFrom. Be aware that there are limitations to the inference supported by OWL 2 RL for some of these properties, e.g. what type of inferences should or should not be done for specific class expressions (OWL restrictions). If you chose OWL 2 RL, check Tables 5-8 in the spec, https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-profiles/#OWL_2_RL. GraphDB's owl-2-rl data set is fully compliant with it. GraphDB is the only major triplestore with full OWL 2 RL compliance - see the this table (https://www.w3.org/2001/sw/wiki/OWL/Implementations) it appears with its former name OWLIM.

My suggestion would be to go with OWL Horst for a large dataset, as reasoning with OWL 2 RL could be much slower. It depends on your ontology and data patterns, but as a rule of thumb you can expect loading/updates to be 2 times slower with OWL 2 RL, even if you don't use extensively its "expensive" primitives (e.g. property chains). See the difference between loading speeds with RDFS+ and OWL 2 RL benchmarked here: http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/benchmark.html

Finally, I would recommend you to use the "optimized" versions of the pre-defined rule-sets. These versions exclude some RDFS reasoning rules, which are not useful for most of the applications, but add substantial reasoning overheads, e.g. the one that infers that the subject, the predicate and the object of a statement are instances of rdfs:Resource

```
Id: rdf1_rdfs4a_4b 
     x  a  y
    -------------------------------
     x  <rdf:type>  <rdfs:Resource>
     a  <rdf:type>  <rdfs:Resource>
     y  <rdf:type>  <rdfs:Resource>
```

If you want to stay 100% compliant with the W3C spec, you should stay with the non-optimized versions.

If you need further assistance, please, write to support@ontotext.com

Comment: I appreciate your response, and I have looked at many of the many of resources you mentioned. Pointing out property chains is helpful, since we do have them in our ontology. However, could you provide some concrete examples? I think this would help not just me, but many others. The resources you mention are quite abstract.

Comment: Bill, I provided several examples in the recording of the webinar [Reasoning with Big Knowledge Graphs: Choices, Pitfalls and Proven Recipes](https://www.ontotext.com/knowledgehub/webinars/reasoning-with-big-knowledge-graphs/) which I made last Thu. I would recommend you to consider avoiding property-chains if the scale of the data is (likely to get) big and update performance is an issue. It will be faster to use psys:transitiveOver in your ontology. E.g. :locatedIn psys:transitiveOver :subRegionOf. This is GraphDB specific. It is supported in rulesets RDFS Plus and OWL Horst

Comment: How do I access the video? The link you gave is to the webinar, not the recording of the webinar.

Comment: "Sign-up for this webinar" and you should be able to get the recording

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Atanas (our CEO) wrote and your excellent example, http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/enterprise/rules-optimisations.html provides some ideas how to optimize your rulesets to make them faster.

Two of the ideas are:

- ptop:transitiveOver is faster than owl:TransitiveProperty: quadratic vs cubic complexity over the length of transitive chains
- ptop:PropChain (a 2-place chain) is faster than general owl:propertyChainAxiom (n-place chain) because it doesn't need to unroll the rdf:List underlying the representation of owl:propertyChainAxiom.

Under some conditions you can translate the standard OWL constructs to these custom constructs, to have **both** standards compliance and faster speed:

- use rule `TransitiveUsingStep`; if every TransitiveProperty `p` (eg `skos:broaderTransitive`) is defined over a step property `s` (eg `skos:broader`) and you don't insert `p` directly
- if you use only 2-step `owl:propertyChainAxiom` then translate them to custom using the following rule, and infer using rule `ptop_PropChain`:

```
Id: ptop_PropChain_from_propertyChainAxiom
  q <owl:propertyChainAxiom> l1
  l1 <rdf:first> p1
  l1 <rdf:rest> l2
  l2 <rdf:first> p2
  l2 <rdf:rest> <rdf:nil>
  ----------------------
  t <ptop:premise1>   p1
  t <ptop:premise2>   p2
  t <ptop:conclusion> q
  t <rdf:type> <ptop:PropChain>
```

http://rawgit2.com/VladimirAlexiev/my/master/pubs/extending-owl2/index.html describes further ideas for extended property constructs, and has illustrations.

Let us know if we can help further.

Comment: Thanks for you comments Vladimir!